# How to to define return type of a function that depends on parameter pack transformation?

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming

I am trying to write a templated function that takes as input a variable number of pairs, applies some function to every "first" member, and every "second" member and returns the pair of results. I managed to write the function itself, but I can't get the return type to be automatically inferred. How to use `std::result_of` to get the desired result?

My attempt is as follows:

```
template<typename Output, typename Func, typename... Inputs>
std::pair<Output, Output> fmap(Func&& f, Inputs&&... inputs)
{
  using Out = typename std::result_of<Func(decltype(inputs.first)...)>::type;
  return std::pair<Out, Out>(f((inputs.first)...),
                             f((inputs.second)...));
  // Here I would like Out to be the same type as Output
}

int add(int i, int j)
{
  return i + j;
}

int main()
{
  std::pair<int, int> pair{1, 2};
  std::pair<int, int> pair2{4, 5};
  auto res = fmap(add, pair, pair2);
  // Crashes with template argument deduction failed, couldn't deduce Output
  std::cout << res2.first << " " << res2.second << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: which version of C++? If I remember correctly since C++17, you can use `auto` and you do not have to define return type it will be auto deduced.

Comment: and use https://wandbox.org/ (or something similar) to provide an example, it would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think this is what you want

```
template<typename Func, typename... Inputs>
auto fmap(Func&& f, Inputs&&... inputs) 
-> std::pair<typename std::result_of<Func(decltype(inputs.first)...)>::type, typename std::result_of<Func(decltype(inputs.first)...)>::type>
{
  using Out = typename std::result_of<Func(decltype(inputs.first)...)>::type;
  return std::pair<Out, Out>(f((inputs.first)...),
                             f((inputs.second)...));
}
```

https://wandbox.org/permlink/TE6v3vgyOBumHCKV

Comment: Thanks this was exactly what I needed. Completely forgot about "->" syntax.

Answer (score 2):

IMO using `make_pair` make this cleaner:

```
template<typename Func, typename... Inputs>
auto fmap(Func&& f, Inputs&&... inputs) 
    -> std::pair<typename std::result_of<Func(decltype(inputs.first)...)>::type, 
                 typename std::result_of<Func(decltype(inputs.first)...)>::type> // not needed in C++17
{
    return std::make_pair(f((inputs.first)...), f((inputs.second)...));
}
```

https://wandbox.org/permlink/MbNhIfoYvHd2vZ7A
https://wandbox.org/permlink/rM6HUcWINOd60EqZ